# Attempting to make a discord bot to display cooldowns

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, embed, countdowntimer

I am a beginner dev.

I am attempting to make a discord bot that will display countdown timers inside an embed.

Currently I’m stuck trying to figure out how to make the timer it’s self. For example when a user types “Boss1”, a message will pop up stating “Boss1 Timed” and a timer will be created inside an embed for, let’s say, 1Hour 30 minutes. Seconds is not necessary. I have created an embed with keywords for each timer. Each time the user types “soon” the embed will show the list of active timers. For example, the user types “Bosslist” and, inside an embed a list of keywords will appear that the user can type and each keyword has a preset time. Would this be easier to preset the time in the code or create another command where the user can instead type (bossname)set(hours)(minutes) to create a timer with those specific keywords? I’ve also eliminated the use of prefix before a command as I enjoy the cleaner look and this bot will be in a specific bot only channel.

Example:
User : Boss1 set 1h30m
Bot: Boss1 time set 1hour 30minutes

User : Boss1
Bot : boss1 timed

User : soon
Embed: >
Boss1 : 1hour 30 mins
Boss2 : 25mins

After time expires I would like the (keyword/boss) to disappear from the embed as well.

Any help?

So far I’ve only been able to create a simple timer that updates consistently and only in seconds but I don’t think it’s quite what I’m looking for either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.